# ViewPagerAdapter returns wrong position

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm developing an application in which i use a `ViewPager`.

Underneath the `ViewPager`, there are some bullet points that should indicate which page is displayed, but their behaviour is wrong.

Here's the activity part:

```
        ind1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.page1);
        ind2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.page2);
        ind3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.page3);
        ind4 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.page4);

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
```

Here's the Adapter:

```
/*Adapter for ViewPager*/
    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position){
            case 0:
                ind1.setImageResource(on);
                ind2.setImageResource(off);
                ind3.setImageResource(off);
                ind4.setImageResource(off);
                return Frag1.newInstance();
            case 1: 
                ind1.setImageResource(off);
                ind2.setImageResource(on);
                ind3.setImageResource(off);
                ind4.setImageResource(off);
                return Frag2.newInstance();
            case 2: 
                ind1.setImageResource(off);
                ind2.setImageResource(off);
                ind3.setImageResource(on);
                ind4.setImageResource(off);
                return Frag3.newInstance();
            case 3: 
                ind1.setImageResource(off);
                ind2.setImageResource(off);
                ind3.setImageResource(off);
                ind4.setImageResource(on);
                return Frag4.newInstance();
            default:
                ind1.setImageResource(on);
                ind2.setImageResource(off);
                ind3.setImageResource(off);
                ind4.setImageResource(off);
                return Frag1.newInstance();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;  /*NUM_PAGES = 4*/
    }
}
```

Here's `Frag1` (the other Fragments are equal to Frag1, the only differences are the layout and the loaded HTML file):

```
public class Frag1 extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_page_1, container, false);
        WebView wv = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/tabel1.html");
        wv.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
        wv.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        return rootView;
    }

    public static Frag1 newInstance(){
        Frag1 f = new Frag1();
        return f;
    }

}
```

The wrong behaviour is the following: when activity starts, the first fragment is displayed but the 'active' bullet point is the second, for the second page the active point is the third, for the third page is active the fourth, for the fourth page the fourth point remains active. If i swipe back to the third page the second bullet point is active.

In simple terms, the active bullet point doesn't match with the displayed page.

I tried to print the position in the `Adapter`, like following, under each `case:`:

```
Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

When activity starts, are printed two consecutive message, `0` and `1`, without interacting with the ViewPager.

When i change page, the `position` is always wrong, but the relative fragment are displayed correctly.

I tried to set the bullet point state in the fragments class, but nothing changed.

Why the adapter indicates the wrong position? How can i make that the correct bullet point indicates the right displayed page?

Comment: ViewPager will load the the visible fragment and the others around him. If you open fragment 3 it will call getView for 2 and 4. If you open 0 it will load 1 aswell

Comment: Ok, but how can i get the the right position of the opened fragment?

Comment: Like in a listview you don't use the adapter to get the current poistion but the list instead. Use `ViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener` to do it

Comment: Ok, i tried, it works fine. I did already try `ViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener`, but always inside the adapter. Bad choice. Thank you